# How do I pass a Base64 string to MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a service where I'm trying to pass an encrypted value to my MVC site, specifically the Home controller. The value is sent as Base64, and I can verify that the Base64 string is correct when creating the URI from within the service. But when the request arrives at my site and processed by my controller the entire value is forced into lowercase, failing the decryption since Base64 is case sensitive. I've tried percent-encoding the string hoping to preserve the casing, but that just brings back a 404.

My route looks like so:

```
routes.MapRoute("ResultsReady", "Results-Ready/{sn}", new { controller = "Home", action = "ResultsReady", sn = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

My controller like so:

```
public ActionResult ResultsReady(string sn)
{
    return Content(sn);
}
```

And my service code builds the URI like so:

```
using (var client = new HttpClient()) 
{
    string base64EncodedValue = SomeFunc();
    var response = client.GetAsync($"https://somewhere.com/Results-Ready/{base64EncodedValue}").Result;
}
```

Comment: It should be a query string or form parameter, not path.

Comment: BASE64 is no an encryption algorithm. If you want to send data, use POST, not GET with a weird URL. If you want to specify parameters in a URL, use the query parameters, not the path. You haven't posted any code that decodes BASE64 or an example of the result, so one can't even guess what you refer to by lowercase - lowercase BASE64 string? Lowercase decoded result? Are you using [Convert.FromBase64String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.convert.frombase64string?view=net-5.0) or hand-rolled code ?

Comment: What are you trying to do and why? If you want encryption, use HTTPS. That's it. The ASP.NET Core templates use HTTPS by default, you have to turn it off explicitly. Everyone recognizes BASE64 so using that in an unencrypted URL won't protect anything. In fact, proxies and debugging tools like Fiddler may decode it automatically

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Post instead of Get and it works.

As to the questions regarding showing more code; the specifics were always irrelevant. The point was, the method SomeFunc returns a base64 string, period! And when I pass that string as a param passed by url, the website controller was always taking the parameter passed and making it all lowercase. Anyone that understands base64 can see the problem with losing the exact case sensitive string.

Answer (score -1):

Using ajax call, you can send the FormData object.

```
var file = document.getElementById("base64string").src;

var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("base64string", file);

$.ajax({
    url: "@Url.Action("SaveImage")",
    type: "POST",
    data: formdata,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false
});
```

and at controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public void SaveImage(string base64string)
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: This isn't a question about Javascript or how to POST data. What you posted is JQuery, not AJAX (that's just an acronym specifying technologies) and isn't needed either. All browsers support `fetch` natively

Comment: In fact, the question is why the *controller* code fails to decode the string properly. Although the question doesn't contain any of the relevant code, so we have no idea what the problem is